# WP Dashboard -> Posts-> Filter by Category -> Form Method Change : Which Hook

Tags: filters, hooks, dashboard

We have a contemporary 4.2.2 WP install running with a handful of various plugins. We have been facing an issue where when a provisioned user is in the "POSTS" dashboard view, the ability to filter all posts by a category returns the full, unfiltered list.

Looking into it initially I noticed that the request method for the filter posts form (found at the top of the posts list) is OOTB set to `GET`. However, I manually changed this (via inspect element in chrome) to `POST`, then submitted the request.

This worked.

The issue at hand now as I understand it is either something has hooked that filter process to disallow `GET` requests OR has hooked the menu's form itself, and replaced what should be(?i guess?) a `POST` request, with a `GET`

I can't seem to find a filter hook (so I can scour our plugins to see which are wrenching on this attribute) - thank you in advance.

Comment: The fact `POST` works suggests it might be a `GET` request size issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2659995/247223

Comment: In other situations, I would agree. Looking for anything out of the ordinary in plugins and theme functions which were attached to any filter that modified query results, I came across a small add_filter statement which sought to achieve the suppression of taxonomies and terms from site (frontend) search results. They achieved this by slapping a series `-{{cat}}` modifiers to the query clause. Sometime between the old version and new version of core, `!is_admin()` must have been implicit with this filter and that changed, thus searching against the restricted cats was fruitless

Answer (score 0):

the system was apparently, recently updated from a very old version of WP core. there was a customization around taxonomy suppression and the pre_get_posts hook which didn't also consider `is_admin()`